# SFTP users can't remove files

Tags: permissions, sftp

I've set up a simple SFTP server on Ubuntu 18.04.  I have 10 users that should only have access to the files in their home directories and they should not be able to get out of their home directory.

We have an API that is writing files to their home directories.

So far, so good.

The users can login, retrieve the files, and are constrained to their own directories.  They cannot, however, remove the files.  Any 'rm' command returns a permissions error - Couldn't delete file: Permission denied.

The user/group for the folder is root:www-data.  If I change it to user:www-data SFTP breaks - they can't login.  I created a group 'sftp' but again if I add the user to the sftp group, change the home directory to user:sftp they can't login.

Here's what the home folder looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   www-data 172032 Feb  6 14:19 29
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   www-data 135168 Feb  6 14:17 52
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   www-data  69632 Feb  6 14:15 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   www-data  36864 Feb  6 14:14 68
```

My sftp config from /etc/ssh/sshdconfig is:

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

My users are set up like this:

```
29:x:1002:1001::/home/26:/bin/sh
44:x:1003:1003::/home/44:/bin/sh
52:x:1004:1004::/home/52:/bin/sh
68:x:1005:1005::/home/29:/bin/sh
```

My sftp group is:

```
sftp:x:1001:26,44
```

Comment: Your usernames are not valid (cf. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157426/what-is-the-regex-to-validate-linux-users)), so many programs will break in many unexpected ways. Change the owner of the home directories after you fixed the usernames.

Answer (score 1):

Apart the [user naming problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157426/what-is-the-regex-to-validate-linux-users), which should be corrected, but probably has no influence on your use case, your configuration must satisfy two incompatible contraints:

- As specified by the [sshd_config manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory):

  > **ChrootDirectory**
  >   Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. All components of the pathname must be **root-owned directories** that are **not writable** by any other user or group. After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.
- On the other hand you need **user-writable** directories, if you want user's to delete files in their home directory.

Therefore you need to create a directory inside `/home/user`, which will be owned by the user. A prime choice is `/home/user/home/user` to which **sftp** will go after logging in.

Summarizing, if you have users like this:

```
u29:x:1002:1001::/home/u26:/bin/sh
u44:x:1003:1003::/home/u44:/bin/sh
u52:x:1004:1004::/home/u52:/bin/sh
u68:x:1005:1005::/home/u29:/bin/sh
```

you just need to create some directories:

```sh
for user in u29 u44 u52 u68; do
    home=/home/$user
    # Create the chroots owned by root
    mkdir -p $home
    # Create the homes inside the chroots
    mkdir -p $home$home
    # Fix ownership
    chgrp www-data -R $home
    chown root -R $home
    chown $user -R $home$home
    # Fix directory permissions
    find $home -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
    find $home$home -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} +
done
```

The **setgid** on users homes might be useful for your scripts (which run as `www-data` I assume). You might also consider setting the `umask` for **sftp**:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
```

**PS**: I can not understand, why many people insist to **administratively** prohibit users to access each other's home directories. A sound default permission on the home directory (e.g. `700`) and umask (`077`) should be enough. Those who know what they are doing can change their permissions.

Comment: Users don't know what they are doing, and go for "just use permissions 777, the problem goes away" type "solutions"

Comment: Yes, users would do that, since they don't understand neither Windows nor Unix permissions. However, as long as it is their responsibility, the OP would not be to blame.