# Limit documentroot on SFTP with SSHD

Tags: ftp, sftp, proftpd, documentroot

I use proFTPD on debian 8. For some reasons i need users that can only access to their documentroot. I already configured this and it works but only when i connect in FTP.

If the user connect on SFTP, he will be able to access at the entire FTP.

How can i do ?

**EDIT :**

I found how to correct my problem.

1) I stoped proFTD because it cause problems. I swich on the default SSH server od my debian server

2) All of the folders are owned by **root:root** and with **755** perms. In my case, it was `/`, `/var`, `/var/www`, and `/var/www/dev`

3) The SSHD config was :

`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group dev
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/dev
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no`

Comment: Are you sure `SFTP` is provided by **proFTPD** and not **sshd**?

Comment: Yes it was this !

Comment: But how can i install a limit of defaut root for sshd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict some `SFTP` users to a subdirectory of your filesystem, you can use the `ChrootDirectory` option in your **OpenSSH** server config.

Let's assume you want restrict the users of group `ftp-users` to access only the `/var/ftp/%username%` directory (where `%username%` is their username). Then you could use:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftp-users
    ChrootDirectory /var/ftp/%u
```

In the `ChrootDirectory` option you can use `%u` for the username, `%U` for the user id or `%h` for the user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But in my case, it doesn't work. This is my config :
 
Match Group dev
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/dev
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no

Comment: The config looks alright. Did you restart the **ssh** server? What are the logs saying?

Comment: Yes i restarted the server at every modification.
I look at /var/log and didn't found auth.log
It is normal ?

Comment: It depends on `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, but usually facility `auth` and `authpriv` are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`. You can also try `journalctl -u ssh`. Regarding the config: only the first matching `Match` stanza is applied, maybe you have several.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your configuration but it doesn"t work. In my logs there is :
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/dev/"
But i gave root:root to the folder and 777 for the perms.

Comment: The permissions are the problem: all components of `/var/www/dev` (i.e. `/`, `/var`, `/var/www` and `/var/www/dev`) must be owned by root and **not writable** by anyone else (so `755`). This guarantees that the user can not escape the `chroot`. Of course you want your users to be able to write to `/var/www/dev`, so check [this question about sftp permissions](https://serverfault.com/q/1002051/530633).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But all of these files are already owned by root:root and with 755 perms. 
I juste have this error : 
`mars 15 14:29:00 VPS sshd[2686]: Accepted password for dev_cpm_connect from XX.XX.XX.XX port XXXXX ssh2
mars 15 14:29:00 VPS sshd[2686]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dev_cpm_connect by (uid=0)
mars 15 14:29:00 VPS sshd[2688]: subsystem request for sftp by user dev_cpm_connect failed, subsystem not found
mars 15 14:29:00 VPS sshd[2686]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dev_cpm_connect`

Comment: Check whether you have the `Subsystem` option in your configuration. **internal-sftp** is absent on old releases of **ssh** (cf. [this answer by Martin Prikryl](https://serverfault.com/a/660325/530633)), but it should be present on Debian 8.

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Now it's work !

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a secure connection to a FTP server, you can use any application that support SFTP. SFTP (commonly referred to as Secure File Transfer Protocol ) can perform secure file transfers.

Comment: Yes, i do that but how can i desactivate SFTP on proFTPD ?

Comment: imho proftp is delivering ftps and not sftp, this are 2 different protocol handlings the first works with ftp over ssl/tls and the other on 22 ssh