# How to prevent a SFTP user from seeing other directories?

Tags: sftp, file-permissions, windows-server-2019

I'm setting up a Windows Server 2019-based web server. One of our vendors needs to be able to upload files. I have

- Added sshd
- Created a login for them to use
- Created a group for that login
- Added that login to the group, and removed the login from all other groups
- Created an upload directory
- Given the group **Write** and **Modify** permissions in that directory
- Added the line `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d "C:\inetpub\ftproot\Upload"` to a **Match** directive for that group in **sshd_config**

So far, so good. That login can connect to the box via SFTP, and the session automatically begins in the directory **Upload**, and it can upload and download files from there. But I cannot figure out how to prevent it from seeing the contents of other directories. Just removing the login from the group **Users** had no effect. Denying the group **Read** and **List** in the enclosing **ftproot** directory results in being unable to connnect (with an authentication failure). The only suggestion I have found in an hour of Google searching is to set a value for `ChrootDirectory`, but that results in no login being able to connect by SFTP or SSH (with apparent failures of the service to respond). I am pretty new to Windows server, and I'm out of ideas. There must obviously be a right way to do this - can someone point me in the right direction?

**[Update]**

This box is running OpenSSH 7.7:

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

When I add this line to the **Match** directive for the sftp group:

```
ChrootDirectory "C:\inetpub\ftproot\Upload"
```

and then attempt to connect as any user, whether or not in that group, this is what appears in **sshd.log** (obviously the pid, port, and timestamp will vary):

```
3332 2021-08-17 12:04:24.931 Failed password for invalid user sftpuser from XX.XX.XX.XX port 34240 ssh2
```

Comment: Assuming you are using openssh maybe https://serverfault.com/a/1006119/187998 is a solution, if not please provide more details on version and configuration.
Also try to create and look at verbose logfiles.

Comment: I've added what additional information I have. I can't find any doc referring to varying the level of verbosity of the logs.

Comment: What about https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/190#issuecomment-662879084 ?

Comment: @NiKiZe I just tried `LogLevel VERBOSE` but it made no difference in what was logged when I tried to connect.

Comment: Actually several posts further down there was something that seems to be the key: Do *not* use quotation marks in the `ChrootDirectory` path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the key piece here is *not* to use quotation marks around the path in this line:

```
ChrootDirectory C:\inetpub\ftproot\Upload
```

After making that change, making an SFTP connection behaved exactly as I hoped: the directory to which the group is restricted appears as the root.